# Custom UIPickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, custom-controls, uipickerviewcontroller

I have a project where I have a set data model (the model doesn't ever change) that I want to add into a `UIPickerView`.

I am trying to make this `UIPickerView` stretch from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen, but when I set the frame, it won't go past a maximum height that is about half the screen.

I have looked into a couple custom `UIPickerView` classes, but have yet to find anything that will allow me to do this. It is a much that I am able to change the background image of the picker and also change the image for the selection.

Where can I find this? Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide much customization on the UIPickerView.But I think you can definitely depend on a tableview for the purpose.

Have a look at [these](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=picker)

Comment: You just did the same thing as me. Why is this answer needed?

Comment: When i type in,there is no answer for this question.So the answer is needed

Comment: The best option was this one here: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/izvalueselector

Comment: It provided the most customization! Thanks a lot! I am bookmarking this site!

Comment: @KyleBegeman : yeah it is a good choice but the customization is little tricky.I used that once.I will go with tableview since it is more comfortable .Anyways happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Some custom classes can be found at this site [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls):

**For Example at my search [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UIPickerView) I found 15 different customs `UIPickerViews`:**

- [PickerTableViewCell for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/pickertableviewcell)
- [ALPickerView for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/alpickerview)
- [AFPickerView for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/afpickerview)

Try these, AFPickerView would probably be the most likely to work.

---

You could also do this by calling a subview thats bigger than the `iOSDevice's` screen, that holds a `UIPickerView`, this way you can do a hack move to allow for the biggest `UIPickerView` you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SBTableAlert](http://github.com/simonb/SBTableAlert), I was looking for a similar thing as you and found this to be a very good substitute.
I was looking for something like phone number type selector list in contacts edit view, but was not able to find anything of the sort and seemed like it will take quite a bit of time to develop. SBTableAlert is a good option IMHO.